# Extra events getting fired in the asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my ASP .NET MVC application, I need to provide the user the ability to edit his profile. As there are  many fields in the profile, I have broken the profile into three sections. Each section is a page by itself with a corresponding "Save" button. My AccountController class has methods such as:

```
  public ActionResult ProfileSection1() {
       ProfileSection1Model model = ProfileSection1Model.create();
       return View(model);
  }

  public ActionResult ProfileSection1(ProfileSection1Model model) {
       ...logic to save the model
       return View(model);
  }
```

Likewise, I have controller methods and the corresponding views for ProfileSection2 and ProfileSection3.

I can navigate to, for example, `localhost:xxx/Account/ProfileSection1`. All the pages work as expected.

Now, I created a new page, EditProfile, and added a link to each page under a different tab using bootstrap tab control:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="personal">@Html.Action("ProfileSection1")</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="address">@Html.Action("ProfileSection2")</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="public">@Html.Action("ProfileSection3")</div>
</div>
```

I am able to, for example, go to the third tab, edit the values in ProfileSection3 and click on the Save button. On the controller, `ProfileSection3(ProfileSection3Model model)` gets invoked as expected. So far so good.

However, on the controller, `ProfileSection1(ProfileSection1Model model)` is also getting invoked although I haven't even clicked on Save on the first tab.

I am wondering why the incorrect method is getting invoked. More importantly, if there is a way to change this behavior.

I thought of using `iframe` under each tab but would like to avoid iframes if possible. Regards.

Comment: The problem is that model binding / action selection for the child action calls are also using the POST parameters from the original request.  I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Are each of these methods returning different forms? What is the value of the `action` attribute in each of the forms?

Comment: look like you have you single form with multiple submit buttons ? so possibly every controller invokes , can u share generated view source ?

Comment: Steve. Each page independently returns a form. The code for each page was automatically generated using "create view" on the controller methods. So they all have standard action attribute.